# Using C++ Code in yacc file

Tags: c++, c, bison, flex-lexer, yacc

I have an assignment to make, where I have to parse a circuit code to render the SVG of the circuit using flex and bison. I want to use C++ STL to make my life easier, but have been unable to do so. Here is my code:

**Sample.y**

```
%{
void yyerror (char *s);     /* C declarations used in actions */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
%}

.
.
..tokens and grammer....
.
.

int main (void) 
{
    /* init symbol table */
    return yyparse ( );
}

void yyerror (char *s) {fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", s);}
```

**scan.l**

```
%{
#include "Sample.tab.h"
%}
%%
.
.
lexical rules
.
.
%%
int yywrap (void) {return 1;}
```

I have tried many approaches like using extern "C", including yylex(),yyparse etc, but it didn't work. How exactly can I make C++ code work in yacc file? I also know there is an approach where we can make a third 'main.cpp' file and code in that. How exactly will that approach work? Kindly tell what changes do I need to make to my code to make it work. The file works perfectly with C, but cannot use cout, cin etc in this.

Comment: Using C++ code directly in a `yacc`-generated C file isn't really safe.  `yacc`-generated code is C code, and C++ is not C.  Compiling C code as C++ will not generate the same results, and you will not be able to find any bugs introduced because of that. Rather, you should put your C++ code in a dedicated C++ file and *call* functions from the `yacc` code.

Comment: Even I want to follow that approach. But I am unable to implement it. As soon as I get a valid expression, I want to store the details in a map or a vector. How can I have this functionality using a third file? Do I need to use extern?? If yes, then how exactly.

Answer (score 2):

After the first (or every) `%{` you specify the

```
#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif
```

and before every `%}` you specify the

```
#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

If you run yacc and open the generated C file, you see that yacc includes your C or C++ code verbatim (with `$` variables replaced with yacc stack indexes) and includes a basic parser. If you add the C++ directives around it, it will compile as C++. You may also need to adapt file `yaccpar`, which contains the parser template into which yacc inserts its code.

If this doesn't help, you can manually adapt the generated C file: open it and put `extern "C" {` on line 1 and a `}` on the last line.

Comment: It works, but I'd think compiling `yacc`-generated C code as C++ code is a really bad idea. There are differences between the languages - C++ is not C. Any bugs introduced from compiling C code as C++ code are going to be subtle and impossible to find, much less fix.